# Pushing_back value in std::vector without auxiliary variable

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm wondering if it's possible to `push_back` a variable into a `std::vector` without the use of another variable. For quite some time I've been doing this:

```
std::vector<int> v;

int temp;
std::cin >> temp;
v.push_back(temp);
```

I was wondering if it was possible to do the same in a single line:

```
v.push_back(READING_HERE);
```

Comment: You use "variable" and "another variable".  Can you name the *first* variable, and what the "another variable" is, in your code example?  Or, do you mean "push back a *value*" without "using a varaible"?

Answer (score 7):

Sure, but I doubt it's worth the trouble:

```
std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), 1, std::back_inserter(v));
```

`std::istream_iterator` creates a wrapper iterator around `std::cin`, which can be used to read the values from `std::cin`. The `1` is the amount of elements, and then it inserts the value into the vector again.

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44764990/pushing-back-value-in-stdvector-without-auxiliary-variable/44765097?noredirect=1#comment76512206_44765097) by [@T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c), you can even use the following line, which is even shorter:

```
v.push_back(*std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin));
```

Comment: You can do `v.push_back(*std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin));`. "I doubt it's worth the trouble" still applies though.

Comment: In fact, in this this can be written even shorter using braced initializer, so without push_back at all :)

`std::vector<int> v{ *std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin) };`

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the auxiliary variable because then, if the read fails, the contents of your `std::vector` is easier to control and to keep well defined.

But you can do this:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.emplace_back(); // default construct a new int in the vector

std::cin >> v.back(); // read directly into the element you just created
```

Answer (score 2):

Lambdas to the rescue (see it <kbd>[live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8a1ed1e668522c3)</kbd>):

```
v.emplace_back( [&]{ 
    auto i = int{}; 
    if( std::cin >> i )
        return i;
    throw std::runtime_error("Bad input value");
}() ); // IIFE (immediately invoked function expression)
```

Yes, it's cheating a little to call this "one line", but it does check the input for sanity. Compare [this FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#stream-input-failure).

Comment: With prvalue change in C++17, we might want to add `construct_back` to vector's interface (which takes something that returns a prvalue).